# Fedex WSDL C# - Setting the Invoice # value

Tags: c#, fedex

I'm using Fedex's WSDL in C# to generate COD shipping labels.  On Fedex shipping labels there is an "Invoice #" string on both the shipping label and the COD return label.  I want to set my orderid in the request to Fedex such that my orderid shows up as the Invoice #.

It's not obvious to me how to set the Invoice # in Fedex's wsdl request.  Has anybody done this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way in which you place the **order id** or **invoice number** in the labels is following:

1. Set the invoice number in the package customer reference.
2. Specify on the COD details node (on the reference indicator) that you want the COD label to include the invoice number as one of its reference.

Please, note that you can also include other references than invoice number (e.g.: PO, customer reference, and tracking).

Here is a sample SOAP envelope for the request depicting what I said before:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <ProcessShipmentRequest xmlns="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v12">
            <WebAuthenticationDetail>
                <CspCredential>
                    <Key>CSP_KEY(IF YOU ARE ONE)</Key>
                    <Password>CIS_PASSWORD(IF YOU ARE ONE)</Password>
                </CspCredential>
                <UserCredential>
                    <Key>CSP_USER_KEY(IF YOU BELONG TO THE CSP)</Key>
                    <Password>CSP_PASSWORD(IF YOU BELONG TO THE CSP)</Password>
                </UserCredential>
            </WebAuthenticationDetail>
            <ClientDetail>
                <AccountNumber>ACCOUNT_NUMBER</AccountNumber>
                <MeterNumber>METER_NUMBER</MeterNumber>
                <ClientProductId>CLIENT_PRODUCT_ID(IF ONE IS PROVIDED)</ClientProductId>
                <ClientProductVersion>CLIENT_VERSION(IF ONE IS PROVIDED)</ClientProductVersion>
            </ClientDetail>
            <TransactionDetail>
                <CustomerTransactionId>261</CustomerTransactionId>
            </TransactionDetail>
            <Version>
                <ServiceId>ship</ServiceId>
                <Major>12</Major>
                <Intermediate>0</Intermediate>
                <Minor>0</Minor>
            </Version>
            <RequestedShipment>
                <ShipTimestamp>2013-08-21T14:00:00-04:00</ShipTimestamp>
                <DropoffType>REGULAR_PICKUP</DropoffType>
                <ServiceType>PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT</ServiceType>
                <PackagingType>YOUR_PACKAGING</PackagingType>
                <Shipper>
                    <AccountNumber>ACCOUNT_NUMBER</AccountNumber>
                    <Contact>
                        <PersonName>323199 323199</PersonName>
                        <CompanyName>CSP Testing</CompanyName>
                        <PhoneNumber>9012633035</PhoneNumber>
                        <EMailAddress>csp@fedex.com</EMailAddress>
                    </Contact>
                    <Address>
                        <StreetLines>99 Fedex parkway</StreetLines>
                        <City>ALAMEDA</City>
                        <StateOrProvinceCode>CA</StateOrProvinceCode>
                        <PostalCode>94501</PostalCode>
                        <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
                    </Address>
                </Shipper>
                <Recipient>
                    <Contact>
                        <PersonName>323257 323257</PersonName>
                        <CompanyName>CSP Testing</CompanyName>
                        <PhoneNumber>9012633035</PhoneNumber>
                        <EMailAddress>csp@fedex.com</EMailAddress>
                    </Contact>
                    <Address>
                        <StreetLines>124 Fedex parkway</StreetLines>
                        <City>PADUCAH</City>
                        <StateOrProvinceCode>KY</StateOrProvinceCode>
                        <PostalCode>42001</PostalCode>
                        <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
                    </Address>
                </Recipient>
                <Origin>
                    <Contact>
                        <PersonName>323199 323199</PersonName>
                        <CompanyName>CSP Testing</CompanyName>
                        <PhoneNumber>9012633035</PhoneNumber>
                        <EMailAddress>csp@fedex.com</EMailAddress>
                    </Contact>
                    <Address>
                        <StreetLines>99 Fedex parkway</StreetLines>
                        <City>ALAMEDA</City>
                        <StateOrProvinceCode>CA</StateOrProvinceCode>
                        <PostalCode>94501</PostalCode>
                        <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
                    </Address>
                </Origin>
                <ShippingChargesPayment>
                    <PaymentType>SENDER</PaymentType>
                    <Payor>
                        <ResponsibleParty>
                            <AccountNumber>ACCOUNT_NUMBER</AccountNumber>
                            <Contact>
                                <PersonName>CSP Testing</PersonName>
                                <CompanyName>RTC Testing</CompanyName>
                            </Contact>
                            <Address>
                                <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
                            </Address>
                        </ResponsibleParty>
                    </Payor>
                </ShippingChargesPayment>
                <SpecialServicesRequested>
                    <SpecialServiceTypes>COD</SpecialServiceTypes>
                    <CodDetail>
                        <CodCollectionAmount>
                            <Currency>USD</Currency>
                            <Amount>50</Amount>
                        </CodCollectionAmount>
                        <CollectionType>ANY</CollectionType>
                        <ReferenceIndicator>INVOICE</ReferenceIndicator>
                    </CodDetail>
                </SpecialServicesRequested>
                <CustomsClearanceDetail>
                    <DocumentContent>NON_DOCUMENTS</DocumentContent>
                </CustomsClearanceDetail>
                <LabelSpecification>
                    <LabelFormatType>COMMON2D</LabelFormatType>
                    <ImageType>PNG</ImageType>
                    <LabelStockType>PAPER_4X6</LabelStockType>
                </LabelSpecification>
                <RateRequestTypes>ACCOUNTACCOUNT</RateRequestTypes>
                <PackageCount>1</PackageCount>
                <RequestedPackageLineItems>
                    <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
                    <GroupPackageCount>1</GroupPackageCount>
                    <InsuredValue>
                        <Currency>USD</Currency>
                        <Amount>5000</Amount>
                    </InsuredValue>
                    <Weight>
                        <Units>LB</Units>
                        <Value>20</Value>
                    </Weight>
                    <PhysicalPackaging>OTHER</PhysicalPackaging>
                    <ItemDescription>MacBook Pro</ItemDescription>
                    <CustomerReferences>
                        <CustomerReferenceType>INVOICE_NUMBER</CustomerReferenceType>
                        <Value>INVOICE12345</Value>
                    </CustomerReferences>
                    <SpecialServicesRequested>
                        <SpecialServiceTypes>SIGNATURE_OPTION</SpecialServiceTypes>
                        <SignatureOptionDetail>
                            <OptionType>SERVICE_DEFAULT</OptionType>
                        </SignatureOptionDetail>
                    </SpecialServicesRequested>
                </RequestedPackageLineItems>
            </RequestedShipment>
        </ProcessShipmentRequest>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This is the generated shipping label:

[image]

This is the generated COD label:

[image]

I hope my reply is of help to you.

Best!

Comment: your reply must helped him ;)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.  You showed me what I had to do. I used the following in my test application using fedex's wsdl.   
CustomerReference cr = new CustomerReference();
cr.CustomerReferenceType = CustomerReferenceType.INVOICE_NUMBER;
cr.Value = "invoice123";
request.RequestedShipment.RequestedPackageLineItems[0].CustomerReferences = new CustomerReference[1];
request.RequestedShipment.RequestedPackageLineItems[0].CustomerReferences[0] = cr;